# Deploying two Express servers in one application

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, google-cloud-platform, serversocket

I have two express servers opened in a single Node.JS application.

The use case is to open 2 separate sockets to run 2 simultaneous services.

The issue is Google Cloud or Heroku does not provide the access to multiple ports -> No separate ports = No separate sockets.

Is there a way we can open 2 server ports in a single deployment (to get two separate sockets) in any cloud services (Like Google Cloud/AWS/Heroku)?

Or Is there any other workaround?

Comment: AFAIK you could use NGINX, or some reverse proxy to do this. You can even look in to `http-proxy-middleware` node module

Comment: You need to specify the Google Cloud service that you are using. For example, Compute Engine is very different from App Engine.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. In typical MERN stacks I've used [`concurrently`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently) to run both my `React.js` application and `Express.js` application in parallel, in different ports and on the same deployment. A similar setup could be used in this scenario.

The following example has been tested using Google Cloud Platform's [App Engine (Flexible environment)](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/)

Suppose you have a project structure like such:

```
~/project
|- Dockerfile
|- app.yaml
| 
|- service1
|| - index.js
|| - package.json
|| ...
|
|- service2
|| - index.js
|| - package.json
|| ...
```

Assuming your express applications were created using [`express-generator`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-generator), then it is a fact that as of creation, both applications are running on the same port as denoted by this specific line in `./service1/bin/www` and `./service2/bin/www`: `var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');`. Instead, you can leave service1's bin/www the same so that it continues listening to `process.env.PORT` which in this case would be 8080, and instead edit `./service2/bin/www` so that it runs on any specific port you like other than 8080 or 3000, say you wish to run it on port 3005 for example.

Next, you would then have to edit service1's package.json so that on `npm start`, it will run both applications on their respective ports, concurrently. This can be done like such:

```js
"scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently \"node ./bin/www\" \"node ../service2/bin/www\""
  }
```

Unfortunately, concurrently does not come packaged by default and so this command will likely yield unrecognized errors. As such, you can use a Dockerfile whose purpose would be to specify the runtime image as well as the build steps for deployment (npm install both applications, and `npm install -g concurrently` followed by `npm start`)

```
FROM gcr.io/google_appengine/nodejs
COPY . /app/
RUN cd ./service1 && npm install
RUN cd ./service2 && npm install
RUN npm install -g concurrently
CMD cd ./service1 && npm start
```

Finally, provide an `app.yaml` file which will specify the runtime used as well as the environment.

```
runtime: custom
env: flex
```

Comment: In your case, only the service1 is reachable from outside. The service 2 works only locally and can be reach only by the service1. Am I right?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere You're right, Guillaume. I did not take that into consideration when formulating this answer as this method was mainly used to deploy a React + Express application and not an Express 2x application. With this method, every requests would have to pass through service1 and so accessing service2 would nonetheless require some sort of routing from service1 which would defeat the whole purpose of having 2 express services running in-parallel. Nevertheless, I think it should give the OP some ideas that he can base off of to create a solution that works for him.